# Is it safe to disable hddtemp.service

Tags: services

I'm currently trying to reduce the boot time on Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya with systemd and saw that the service hddtemp is taking quite long to boot. So im wondering if its safe to disable it.

Comment: This is a service that I believe monitors hard drive temperature on some Linux systems.  Please define "safe".

Comment: How long is your boot-time and how much are you hoping to shave off that time without breaking the system. If you want to learn this kind of stuff consider running Linux Mint in a VM with regular snapshots so you can easily roll-back to a working state.